# How to specify KeyValueTextInputFormat Separator in Hadoop-.20 api?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In new API (apache.hadoop.mapreduce.KeyValueTextInputFormat) , how  to specify separator (delimiter) other than tab(which is default) to separate key and Value.

Sample Input :

```
one,first line
two,second line
```

Ouput Required :

```
Key : one
Value : first line
Key : two
Value : second line
```

I am specifying KeyValueTextInputFormat as :

```
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Sample");

    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    KeyValueTextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/input.txt"));
```

This is working fine for tab as a separator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the newer API you should use `mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator` configuration property.

Here's an example:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ",");

Job job = new Job(conf);
job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
// next job set-up
```

Comment: For new api this wont work. Here the entire line will be taken as key

Comment: @chiastic-security: that didnt worked for me , but this did conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");

Answer (score 5):

Please set the following in the Driver Code.

```
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");
```

Comment: Thanx for d response..
But actually i am using new API (Job Object instead of JobConf Object).

Answer (score 1):

For *KeyValueTextInputFormat* the input line should be a key value pair seperated by *"\t"*

```
Key1     Value1,Value2
```

By changing default seperator, You will be able to read as you wish.

For New Api

[Here is the solution](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/can-we-change-default-key-value-input.html)

```
//New API
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ","); 
Job job = new Job(conf);
job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
```

Map

```
public class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    System.out.println("key---> "+key);
    System.out.println("value---> "+value.toString());
   .
   .
```

Output

```
key---> one
value---> first line
key---> two
value---> second line
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a sequence matter.

The first line `conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",")` must come before you create an instance of `Job` class. So:

```
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ","); 
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the new API did not finished in 0.20.* so if you want to use new API in 0.20.*, you should implement the feature by yourself.For example you can use FileInputFormat to achieve.
Ignore the LongWritable key, and split the Text value on comma yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `KeyValueTextInputFormat` class uses tab as a separator for key and value from input text file.

If you want to read the input from a custom separator, then you have to set the configuration with the attribute that you are using.

For the new Hadoop APIs, it is different:

```
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
public class KeyValueTextInput extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String log4jConfPath = "log4j.properties";
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new KeyValueTextInput(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

> Configuration conf = this.getConf();

```
        //conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");
```

> conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator",
>   ",");

```
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "WordCountSampleTemplate");
        job.setJarByClass(KeyValueTextInput.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        //job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        //job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(outputPath.toString()), conf);
        fs.delete(outputPath, true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(Text k1, Text v1, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(k1, v1);
    }
}

class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text Key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String sum = " || ";
        for (Text value : values)
            sum = sum + value.toString() + " || ";
        context.write(Key, new Text(sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: While a full example is nice, it would be better to break this down into the essential parts, with some explanation of what is being done.  Without context, it's a little difficult to find the actual answer.

Comment: To me the answer seems correct, and easy to understand, Also another benefit for me was, I just copied the whole code, and ran it, it ran successfully, now I am modifying the things the way I want, It saved me a good amount of time.