# Customizing InputFormat in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, customization, key-value

I'm trying to read form a very big database which consists of geo-referenced time series data. SO I have the file in the following format:

latitude,longitude,value@time1,value@time2,....value@timeN.

So this is the data for the entire earth.
Now for my work I need to get the latitude,longitude as the key and the time series values as the value.
As far as I know Hadoop has KeyValueInputFormat but it considers first tab as the delimiter.
Is there a way to customize it? I need a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with

```
key.value.separator.in.input.line
```

in job config.

Comment: can you point to a tutorial which can help me to do this. I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211151/how-to-specify-keyvaluetextinputformat-separator-in-hadoop-20-api