# KeyValueTextInputFormat comma separator

Tags: configuration, hadoop

I am using KeyValueTextInputFormat for reading/processing a comma separated file :

> 100,56 
>   89,586
>   123,68

However I get all the value in key, value field is coming as null, even after giving separator as comma (,). It is not picking the separator, not sure what is the issue,, here is my driver code:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");
    Job job = new Job(conf, "citation data");
    job.setJarByClass(Citation.class);
    job.setJobName("citation data");
    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    KeyValueTextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("input/sample.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("output2"));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify KeyValueTextInputFormat Separator in Hadoop-.20 api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211151/how-to-specify-keyvaluetextinputformat-separator-in-hadoop-20-api)

Comment: @ChrisGerken - Not duplicate as such, here the issue is the value field is coming as null

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine for me. In one of my mapred code, I just changed the following and it worked :

1. Changed the InputFormatClass to use `KeyValueTextInputFormat`
2. Added the config - `conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");`
3. Made sure than in the mapper has a look of something like `Mapper<Text,Text,K,V>`, which would make the map() method's signature to be something like this:

> public void map(**Text** key, **Text** value, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter)
>                 throws IOException {}

No other change is required and you must get the first column's data as *key* and second column as *value*.

I guess the only thing you might have missed is the point 3.