# InputFormat Decision

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to figure out which of the given answers suits best the question:

> Given a directory of files with the following structure: line number,
>   tab character, string:
>
> **[Example](http://pastebin.com/rPX4rfS7):**
>
> 1abialkjfjkaoasdfjksdlkjhqweroij
>
> 2kadfjhuwqounahagtnbvaswslmnbfgy
>
> 3kjfteiomndscxeqalkzhtopedkfsikj
>
> You want to send each line as one record to your Mapper. Which
>   InputFormat should you use to complete the line: conf.setInputFormat
>   (____.class) ; ?
>
> A. SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat
>
> B. SequenceFileInputFormat
>
> C. KeyValueFileInputFormat
>
> D. BDBInputFormat

**My analysis:**

**Option A** is a format I found to exist, but I'm not sure of the correct usage of it and if it suits as an answer.

**Option B** is not possible since SequenceFiles are file of binary data (K,V) pairs of binary data, and thus will not be suitable..

**Option C** is not possible because there is no KeyValueFileInputFormat, though here, if it is a typo and it actually is KeyValuetextInputFormat, than I think it will be a good choice. Or isn't it?

**Option D** is not possible because there is no BDBInputFormat and even if it is a typo and it actually is BDInputFormat than it wouldn't suit the case.

Thank You!
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Option C**. It may be a typo

`KeyValueTextInputFormat` helps you to get line splitted with TAB.
So line number will be the key and the string will be the value.

Comment: Thank you, Can you please elaborate on why it can't be the first option?

Comment: A cannot be the answer because of the same reason of B, `SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat` also reads in a SequenceFile and emit's out key, value pairs by calling `.toString` on the key's and value's. Ref: [SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat.html)

Comment: @theexplorer: Yes exactly same as what Ashrith said . once you load that sample data in your mapper setting SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat it shows "java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: file: not a SequenceFile"

Answer (score 1):

It maybe a typo in the option C as you guessed, and it should be https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/KeyValueTextInputFormat.html.

See for more details: [How to specify KeyValueTextInputFormat Separator in Hadoop-.20 api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211151/how-to-specify-keyvaluetextinputformat-separator-in-hadoop-20-api)