# Hadoop Questions Please answer

Tags: hadoop

Please answer for below questions

1)Given a directory of files with the following structure: line number, tab character, string:

Example:

> 1   abialkjfjkaoasdfjksdlkjhqweroij
>
> 2   kadfjhuwqounahagtnbvaswslmnbfgy
>
> 3   kjfteiomndscxeqalkzhtopedkfsikj

You want to send each line as one record to your Mapper. Which InputFormat should you use to
complete the line: conf.setInputFormat (____.class) ; ?

A. SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat

B. SequenceFileInputFormat

C. KeyValueFileInputFormat

D. BDBInputFormat

2)You want to perform analysis on a large collection of images. You want to store this data in HDFS
and process it with MapReduce but you also want to give your data analysts and data scientists
the ability to process the data directly from HDFS with an interpreted high-level programming
language like Python. Which format should you use to store this data in HDFS?

A. SequenceFiles

B. Avro

C. JSON

D. HTML

E. XML

F. CSV

3)Which process describes the life cycle of a mapper.

A. The jobTracker calls the TaskTracker’s configure() method, then, its map() method and finally its close() method.

B. Task Tracker spawns a new mapper process to process all records of a single InputSplit.

C. Task Tracker spawns a new mapper process to process each key-value pair.

D. JobTracker spawns a new mapper process to process all records of single input file.

4)Which of the following best describes the workings of TextInputFormat?

A. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses tile splits is ignored.

B. The input file is split exactly at the line breaks, so each Record Reader will read a series of blocks.

C. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReaders of both splits containing the broken line.

D. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReader of the split that contains the end of the broken line.

E. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReader of the split that contains the beginning of the broken line.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

C- KeyValueFileInputFormat

More info here: [InputFormat Decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930385/inputformat-decision)

**Answer 2:**

A- Sequence Files

More info here: http://www.aiopass4sure.com/cloudera-exams/ccd-410-exam-questions/which-format-should-you-use-to-store-this-data-in-hdfs.html

**Answer 3:**

C- Task Tracker spawns a new mapper process to process each key-value pair.

More info here: http://www.aiopass4sure.com/cloudera-exams/ccd-410-exam-questions/which-process-describes-the-lifecycle-of-a-mapper.html

**Answer 4**

D- Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReader of the split that contains the end of the broken line.

More info here: http://www.aiopass4sure.com/cloudera-exams/ccd-333-exam-questions/which-of-the-following-best-describes-the-workings-of-textinputformat.html