# What are the main differences between KeyValueTextInputFormat and TextInputFormat in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can somebody give me one practical scenario where we have to use `KeyValueTextInputFormat` and `TextInputFormat`??

Answer (score 7):

The `TextInputFormat` class converts every row of the source file into  key/value types where the BytesWritable key represents the offset of the record and the Text value represents the entire record itself.

The `KeyValueTextInputFormat` is an extended version of TextInputFormat , which is useful when we have to fetch every source record as Text/Text pair where the key/value were populated from the record by splitting the record with a fixed delimiter.

Consider the Below file contents,

```
AL#Alabama
AR#Arkansas
FL#Florida
```

If `TextInputFormat` is configured , you might see the key/value pairs as,

```
0    AL#Alabama
14   AR#Arkansas
23   FL#Florida
```

if `KeyvalueTextInputFormat` is configured with `conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", "#")` , you might see the results as,

```
AL    Alabama
AR    Arkansas
FL    Florida
```

Answer (score 0):

keyvaluetextinputformat lets you specify the key from the input file  where as textinputfileformat has a fixed key which is the byte offset.

Set the separator for keyvaluetextinputformat using :

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ",");
```

E.g. of place where you can use keyvaluetextinputformat is :

You get a file which is comma/ some byte separated and you know the first column can act as the key. Lets says CSV of salary with first column as Name/ Employee Id & second column as salary.

Also refer to this post : [How to specify KeyValueTextInputFormat Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211151/how-to-specify-keyvaluetextinputformat-separator-in-hadoop-20-api)